# Difference between two list

Tags: python

I have the following text file:

```
text1 text2
# text2 text3 text4
# text5 text4 text6
text 3 text 4
# ....
...
```

I would like to have a array list like the following, where fu

```
dict[function([text1, text2])] = [[text2, text3, text4], [text5, text4, text6]].
```

The idea is to open the file, read line by line

```
dict = {}
inputfile = open("text.txt","r")
for line in inputfile:
    l=line.split()
if not line.startswith("#"):
#create a new key
else: 
dict[key] = l
```

However, the problem is that I cannot assign other element if I go to the next line. Do you know how to solve this issue?

"Function"is just a function which I defined elsewhere and that takes as an input a list of strings.

Comment: What is `function([text1, text2])`?

Comment: It is just another function which I defined elsewhere and that takes as an input a list of strings.

Comment: you want something like this ? `mydict = { "text1":[text2, text3, text4], "text2":[text5, text4, text6] }`
then 
function([mydict["text1"] ,mydict["text2"]]) ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `collections.defaultdict` to create a dictionary with `list`s as the values to which you can append items.

```
from collections import defaultdict

my_dict = defaultdict(list)

with open('text.txt') as f:
    key = ''
    for line in f:
        if not line.startswith('#'):
            key = line
            # key = function(line.split())
            continue
        my_dict[key].append(line.strip('#').split())

print(my_dict)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>,
            {'text1 text2\n': [['text2', 'text3', 'text4'],
                               ['text5', 'text4', 'text6']],
             'text3 text4\n': [['text21', 'text31', 'text41'],
                               ['text51', 'text41', 'text61']]})
```

Just change the `key = line` line to whatever function you're passing the key to.

My `text.txt` file contains:

```
text1 text2
# text2 text3 text4
# text5 text4 text6
text3 text4
# text21 text31 text41
# text51 text41 text61
```

Comment: Thanks. A quick follow up:
suppose that my line contains the characters " -*-" at the end of the line. I want to remove that. The problem is that I cannot use strip() because a "-" can appear in the rest of the line
my idea was
 
    l_temp = line.strip('#').split()

    l  = l_temp[:-4]

Comment: Have a look at the [`str.rstrip()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_rstrip.htm) method.